# compare a character with various character classes in c++

Tags: c++, comparison, character

The problem is that I want to compare the characters in a string, one by one: for each one, does it belong to the alphabet; is it lowercase or uppercase. How could I do this?

this is fine what if i want to compare it like with(+-*^) like there is no standard function.
plz help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

...

for (std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    if (std::isalpha(*i))
        handle_alphabetic_character(*i);
    else
        handle_non_alphabetic_character(*i);
```

EDIT for new requirement:

To find characters in an arbitrary character set, you could use either str::find() as James MeNellis documents in his answer, or simply...

```
#include <cstring>

for (std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    if (std::strchr("*+{\\&", *i))
        handle_matching_character(*i);
    else
        handle_non_matching_character(*i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use the `std::find` algorithm:

```
const std::string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

bool is_in_alphabet 
           = std::find(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(), 'c') != alphabet.end();
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::binary_search` if the alphabet characters are sorted, but unless you have a large number of characters in the alphabet (i.e., a lot more than 26), a linear search will likely be much faster.  Characters are small and quick to compare.

Comment: The linear search starts to degrade in performance (compared to binary search) when the size is >= 4. What's the definition of large number of characters? :)

Comment: @Jörgen:  Well, binary search is _in theory_ faster for four or more characters.  _In practice_, it's far slower even for e.g. 32 characters, for two reasons:  one, a linear search is far simpler and is more likely to be inlined by the compiler; two, the chance of a mispredicted branch in a binary search is relatively high, while in a linear search, branch prediction isn't really important.  1,024 characters would probably be "large enough for binary search," and 32 i probably "small enough for linear search;" where the cutoff is likely depends on the platform and I'd profile it to see.

Comment: I did some profiling. For worst case scenarios, binary search beats linear search every time for n > 4. For the general case scenarios, binary search beats linear search when n > 19. This makes sense (to me at least), because the binary search code is quite "dense" and has equally many conditional branches as the linear search, so the branch predictor should not have that big of an impact. I did the  profiling using VS 2008 (/O2) and STL's find/binary_search on an intel Q9400.

Comment: @Jörgen:  Interesting.  A few months ago I did similar tests with Visual C++ 2010 and Intel C++ 11.1 and had quite the opposite result:  neither compiler inlined a call to `std::binary_search` where it was being used, and in both cases `std::find` was far more performant.